# Hibernate Exception errors in named queries

Tags: hibernate, named-query

Hi I am using hibernate named queries in my application while executing the named query I am getting some exception the query is

```
@NamedQuery(name="fetchCTCByReferenceIdByPendingApproval",
                query="from icici.ctc.model.CTCChargeTakingCertificate ctc where ctc.idkey = :referenceId and ctc.ctcWorkFlowItem.actionPendingBy = :approverId and trunc(ctc.created_on) > '24-APR-2015'")
```

exception is

```
0:25:00,765 ERROR [jsp:154] org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: fetchCTCByReferenceIdByPendingApprov
       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:426)
       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
       at icici.ctc.system.ServiceLocator.getHibernateSessionFactory(ServiceLocator.java:37)
       at icici.ctc.system.OpenSessionInViewPhaseListener.beforePhase(OpenSessionInViewPhaseListener.java:33)
       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228)
       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)
       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
       at org.portletfaces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:391)
       at org.portletfaces.bridge.GenericFacesPortlet.doView(GenericFacesPortlet.java:181)
       at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)
       at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
       at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:101)
       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:92)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
```

Comment: Is there any "Caused by" in your stacktrace or is it the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply there are no caused by.

Comment: Can you remove `last condition from query (with `trunc`) to see if it works without it?

Comment: Maybe the `trunc` function is not suported by hibernate

Comment: OK I'll try to run without trunc

Comment: getting same issue @NamedQuery(name="fetchCTCByReferenceIdByPendingApproval",
    query="from icici.ctc.model.CTCChargeTakingCertificate ctc where ctc.idkey = :referenceId and ctc.ctcWorkFlowItem.actionPendingBy = :approverId and (ctc.created_on) > '24-APR-2015'"),

Comment: I am using hibernate 2.0

Comment: You should not compare dates as strings in hql, use parameter for date. Change the last condition to `and ctc.created_on > :dateParam` and just supply the value for `dateParam` when you call the query.

Comment: if i'll do like this @NamedQuery(name="fetchCTCByReferenceIdByPendingApproval", query="from icici.ctc.model.CTCChargeTakingCertificate ctc where ctc.idkey = :referenceId and ctc.ctcWorkFlowItem.actionPendingBy = :approverId and (ctc.created_on) > 24-APR-2015")

Comment: You cannot be using Hibernate 2.0. You can't even download that project version any more, it's like 9 years old.

Comment: Sorry I am using hibernate 3.0 hibernate jap 2.0